# VLOOKUP 3 Columns

Tags: excel, vlookup

How would I write a VLOOKUP formula that will:

If: any TEAM Name in Column P occurs in either Column K or Column L
THEN: provides me with the TEAM's corresponding email address in Column N

[image: Schedule]

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=iferror(vlookup("greeley", k:n, 4, false), vlookup("greeley", l:n, 3, false))
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jeeped, but would suggest adding another iferror to handle when the value of column P is not in either K or L.  This concern was prompted from seeing variations in column P. IE: 'Bonny Eagle' also had 'Bonny Eagle 7th', and 'EMYL' also had 'EMYL #'

```
    =IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(P2,K:N,4,FALSE),VLOOKUP(P2,L:N,3,FALSE)),"Unknown")
```